# How did Terrans gain information about the Mars knights' cataphracts?

Tags: aldnoah-zero

After the time skip of 18 months in season 1, the Terrans' knowledge of Martian cataphracts has suddenly increased, so much so that they are able to identify the name of the cataphract and its owner as well.

What led to this intel for terrans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had watched episode 12 of the first season, then you should know that the battle at [Saazbaum](http://aldnoahzero.wikia.com/wiki/Saazbaum)'s [Landing Castle](http://aldnoahzero.wikia.com/wiki/Landing_Castle) ended with the Earth forces' victory. That would mean they obtained all the castle's facilities and all the information contained on that fortress. With Inaho being able to use the Aldnoah Drive, they could have reactivated the fortress and retrieved the information from it, or they just ripped out the hard disks and scanned them for data. However, judging from the fact that Inaho was using his Drive on [Deucalion](http://aldnoahzero.wikia.com/wiki/Deucalion), they most likely just salvaged information instead of reactivating it.

[image]